# Autocomplete delay of JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I got customized `JComboBox` which has the ability of autocomplete. It has attached KeyListener where I call `HttpClient.send(request)` and it returns some result array which I show in dropdown of combo box. For example, user starts typing "a" and the dropown offers all the results which starts with the letter a. The issue is I would like to wait like 2 seconds after the last character is written (so it won't send request after every key input), otherwise the app is laggy (response takes some time). I was thinking about using `Runnable` interface:

1. save time of last key press (using `System.currentTimeMillis`) into `last` variable
2. wait for 2 seconds
3. check if the value in `last` is still the same
4. if true, send request

The idea is if in those 2 seconds user types another character, the value of variable last is updated. Is this bad approach? Is it even doable? I got literally zero experience with multithreading. Can you give me an advice if I should do it this way or if there is some easier way?

Comment: If possible, I would download the entire list and display an appropriate sub-list in the `JComboBox`. That would save having to send multiple HTTP requests. Also, I think that a [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) is more appropriate than a `KeyListener`.

Comment: Yeah that would be easy, but I use an external non-downloadable database. So that's not possible.

Comment: Query the database and select all possible values and store them in a `java.util.List`. No need to download the database. How many values are there? A `List` can easily hold thousands of values.

Comment: For database queries I use an API which demands at least 3 character input. So yeah, I could theoretically call it for every possible case ("aaa", "aab", "aac",..., "zzz"). But this is nonsense, there must be more elegant solution.

Comment: You could test for three or more input characters since that's what your API supports.  Make sure you're querying the API on a different thread than the GUI [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use kotlin coroutines ,
you can save your request in coroutine and cancel it when user type another letter

Comment: I don't use Kotlin.